# Темп выполнения операций

Tags: c#, потоки-данных, очередь

Имеется очередь каких-то атомарных операций, в моем случае это порции данных, которые загружаются в БД, также это может быть, например, очередь файлов при копировании. Я хочу вычислять и выводить темп выполнения этих операций, ну, например, чтобы в любой момент я видел, что за последнюю минуту выполнилось 20 операций или, например, 120. Супер точность при этом не нужна - отклонение в 2-5 единиц считаю допустимым.
Параллельно в эту же очередь извне могут добавляться еще порции данных, поэтому просто делать отпечаток количества элементов в очереди не получится.
Как это реализовать?

---

Пока набирал вопрос, возникло примерно вот такое решение:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Timers;

class Program : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().Run();

    int count = 0;
    int[] tablet = new int[60];

    public int Tempo => tablet.Sum();

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void Snick()
    {
        ++count;
    }

    void Cut()
    {
        int s = DateTime.Now.Second;
        tablet[s] = count;
        count = 0;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Tempo)));
    }

    void Run()
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000);
        timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => Cut();
        timer.Start();
        // ...
        while (true)
        {
            // ...
            Snick();
        }

        timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Но оно мне пока не до конца нравится, хотя бы тем, что здесь вводится массив и таймер, если я вдруг захочу выводить темп за 1 с - нагрузка от таймера может стать существенной, так же не понятно на какие отрезки разбивать.

Может у кого-то есть уже готовое решение, которое лучше?

Comment: на интервале в 1 с нагрузка от таймера не будет существенной, на 1 мс - возможно, хотя тоже под сомнением, таймер в отдельном потоке работает. А вот использовать для подсчета  `DateTime.Now` - глупость, заведите статический счетчик вызова метода, по таймеру фиксируйте значение счетчика и обнуляйте.

Comment: Да, но у меня более 40 таких очередей в разных потоках и к каждому потоку добавить еще один - уже может быть накладно. Но опять же, я могу использовать таймер один на все очереди...

Comment: зачем к каждому, таймер один. к каждому потоку нужно будет добавить только инкремент счетчика выполненных действий

Comment: Кстати, посмотрел сейчас метод Stopwatch.GetTimestamp(): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.gettimestamp(v=vs.110).aspx - он как раз и берет свое значение из DateTime.Now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А почему так сложно?

Вот такой простой код должен работать:

```
TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

long OperationsDuringLastMinute { get; private set; }

async void RegisterOperation()
{
    OperationsDuringLastMinute++;
    await Task.Delay(timeout);
    OperationsDuringLastMinute--;
}
```

В конце каждой операции вызывайте `RegisterOperation` (в главном потоке).

---

Если у вас не UI-контекст, то, как подсказывает @Raider в комментариях, вам понадобятся атомарные операции.

```
long operationsDuringLastMinute;
long OperationsDuringLastMinute
{
    get { return Interlocked.Read(ref operationsDuringLastMinute); }
}

async void RegisterOperation()
{
    Interlocked.Increment(ref operationsDuringLastMinute);
    await Task.Delay(timeout);
    Interlocked.Decrement(ref operationsDuringLastMinute);
}
```

Comment: Я не до конца понимаю работу тасков, но этот код не создаст 100 (по числу выполненных операций) висящих в фоне ничего не делающих потоков? Или это как-то всё должно хитро оптимизироваться в итоге?

Comment: @Андрей: Нет, конечно, никаких 100 потоков! Таск, висящий в await, вовсе не занимает никакого потока.

Comment: Ну тогда это именно то, что мне нужно, спасибо!

Comment: @Андрей: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло. Обязательно почитайте и разберитесь с async/await, это очень мощная техника.

Comment: @Андрей Советую вам тоже разобраться c async/await, и конкретно c `Task.Delay`. Этот код создаст 100 таймеров (по числу выполненных операций), каждый их которых по истечению минуты попытается взять по потоку из Thread Pool (или вернуться в UI synchronization context, но это не наш случай), чтобы выполнить операцию декремента, которая еще и не атомарная. По сравнению с этим, вариант автора с 1 таймером и ненужным массивом выглядит уже не так криво.

Comment: @Raider: И насколько велика стоимость таймера по сравнению с многопоточной операцией? Вы предлагаете экономить на спичках, так никогда не написать хорошего кода.

Comment: @VladD Вы не те стоимости сравниваете. Цели должны оправдывать средства. Создавать регулярно по 100 таймеров - это нагрузка и на GC (а когда работает GC, то все потоки останавливаются), и на Thread Pool (по истечению `timeout` таймеры полезут ставить коллбэки в очередь) только ради того, чтобы посчитать количество операций я считаю чрезмерным.

Comment: @Raider: Сто объектов в минуту — это нагрузка? При наличии асинхронных операций? Вы наверное шутите.

Comment: @VladD Если задача -- посчитать количество операций, то однозначно да. Учитесь писать хороший код сразу, не откладывайте на потом.

Comment: @Raider:Нет, мне не кажется ваш подход адекватным. А вот за `Thread.Sleep` я бы выгонял из команды, если честно.

Comment: @VladD А я выгоняю за `async void` и непонимание того, что стоит за синтаксическим сахаром, где его уместно использовать (например, в  UI), а где -- нет (например, при замерах производительности). Так что слава богу я не в вашей команде.

Comment: @Raider: Тогда нам придётся договориться, что у нас разные мнения.

Comment: Друзья, вы запутываете меня еще сильнее. Вчера испытал код @VladD на практике и в общем-то он работает как надо, когда у меня поток один темп составляет до 250-300 операций в минуту, но когда их уже 10, то он проседает до 70-100 (это всё разные БД на разных удаленных хостах), не утверждаю, что это связано с нагрузкой от кучи таймеров, но факт налицо. При этом одно ядро процессора загружено всегда на 100%, а процессор в моей программе никогда не был узким местом. Сегодня попробую свой вариант, в нём я использую один статический объект таймера, который точно породит всего один поток.

Comment: @Андрей: Несчастные 1000 объектов в минуту не должны садить производительность. Попробуйте по-всякому, но думаю, что проблема тут скорее в борьбе за общий ресурс.

Answer (score 3):

Если нужно отслеживать выполнение какой-либо длительной операции независимо от неё самой, в любом случае понадобится 2 потока, и какая-то общая область памяти, куда будет записываться общий прогресс.

Таймер здесь не нужен: во-первых, для него берется еще один (не вдаваясь в подробности) ненужный поток из thread pool, во-вторых, его точность уж совсем хромает, и не для того он был создан.

Для замеров точных меток времени в .NET есть класс `Stopwatch`, но так как ваша задача - посчитать *количество операций* за последнюю минуту, то переменной с предыдущим замером в сочетании с `Thread.Sleep` будет достаточно. При желании, `Stopwatch`и `Thread.Sleep` можно скомбинировать для получения более точного результата.

Для наглядности, я использовал квантование по секунде, но интервал легко меняется параметром метода:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static readonly ConcurrentQueue<string> Results = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task work = Task.Run(new Action(DoWork));
        MeasureRate(work, Results);
        Console.WriteLine("Completed!");
    }

    private static void MeasureRate<T>(IAsyncResult work, IReadOnlyCollection<T> results, int timing = 1000 /* 1 second */)
    {
        int previousCount = 0;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Current rate: {0} entries per second", results.Count - previousCount);
            previousCount = results.Count;
            Thread.Sleep(timing);
        } while (!work.IsCompleted);
    }

    private static void DoWork()
    {
        var randomizer = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(randomizer.Next(100));
            Results.Enqueue("Result " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваш вариант мне не подходит, т.к. вы вычисляете среднюю скорость за всё время, а мне нужно именно число операций за последнюю минуту, так как работа организована примерно следующим образом: пока есть элементы в очереди - работаем с ними, когда они закончились - засыпаем на полчаса (или час), затем опять проверяем состояние очереди.

Comment: Источник данных у меня один - процесс-сканер и 40 процессов работающих с БД, этот сканер сканирует некоторую папку (папки) и при появлении в них файлов формирует порции данных и помещает их в очередь одного из 40 процессов. После обработки всех файлов он также засыпает на час.

Comment: Тогда нужно просто сохранять предыдущий замер в переменной, и каждую минуту вычитывать разницу. Я обновил пример кода.

Comment: Хорошо, вашу идею понял и принял к сведению, но у вас не совсем то, смотрите для чего в моем варианте массив int[60] - т.е. мне не нужно получать количество операций за каждую конкретную минуту, а за последнюю минуту, т.е непрерывно каждую секунду у меня есть количество операций за последние 60 сек. Т.е. в 00:01:00 у меня будет отображаться количество выполненных за промежуток 00:00:00-00:01:00; в 00:01:01 - количество выполненных за промежуток 00:00:01-00:01:01 и т.д. В моем примере данные обновляются каждую секунду, если я захочу обновлять каждые 5 с, то хватит массива из 12 чисел, например.

Comment: Т.е. счетчик, который будет каждую минуту сбрасываться в ноль и опять набегать? И зачем нужен массив, если вам нужна только последняя минута?

Comment: Ну как вам объяснить... Мне нужно знать количество операций за последние 60 с, т.е если я буду просто подсчитывать операции, то мне нужно будет каждую секунду вычитать из счетчика то, что произошло 61 с назад.

Comment: Откорректировал немного свой вариант, может так понятнее... Я храню массив количеств операций за последние 60 секунд, при выполнении операции я подсчитываю их в отдельном счетчике, по таймеру каждую секунду я заменяю в массиве количество операций, которые были выполнены 61 с назад на новое значение и обнуляю счетчик (ну тут естественно надо еще блокировку добавить)

Comment: Какой смысл заносить срез по каждой секунде в массив, почему нельзя сразу суммировать? В моем примере я как раз и вычитаю предыдущий результат.

Comment: Да что ж такое. Что с чем суммировать? Вы вычитаете каждую секунду, т. е. у вас там хранится количество операций только в последнюю секунду. Если поменять на 60 с, то будет храниться количество операций за минуту, но и обновляться будет раз в минуту. Мне же надо хранить количество операций за последнюю минуту, а обновлять каждую секунду.