# Ограничение количества запросов

Tags: c#

Оправляю запросы на сервер N раз в минуту, при этом на сервере ограничение - не больше 20 запросов за 30 секунд.

При этом отсчёт времени начинается после каждого сообщения. Проще говоря: если ты за 30 сек до этого запроса отправил ещё 20 - иди лесом.

Как правильно написать проверку того, сколько было оправлено сообщений за 30 сек?

Пока мысль по типу "сохранять текущее время в массив после каждого сообщения, и проверять, сколько элементов в массиве удовлетворяют проверку в 30 сек". Однако чую, что можно всё сделать красивее и правильнее.

Comment: Это посмотрите: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/593598/218063 Почти то что вам надо, перед отправкой просто смотрите значение в `OperationsDuringLastMinute` и если оно уже равно 20, то не отправляете запрос

Comment: @АндрейNOP что-то работает не так. Вызываю `RegisterOperation` после каждой операции, но `OperationsDuringLastMinute` даже спустя минуту не убавляется.

Comment: а строчка `Interlocked.Decrement(ref operationsDuringLastMinute)` выполняется? Поставьте брейкпоинт и посмотрите, может вы слишком большое значение в `Task.Delay` указали?

Comment: @АндрейNOP я понял. Я просто в цикле указал вызов `RegisterOperation`, а все `Task.Delay` срабатывали после цикла. Пока не знаю, будет ли это проблемой.

Comment: Проблемой не будет, просто перед тем как регистрировать операцию, проверяйте, можно ли сейчас эту операцию выполнить: *если оно уже равно 20, то не отправляете запрос*

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, всё отлично. Оформите как ответ?

Comment: Ну, так тоже нормально :)

Comment: Так положено ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Плюсик вы можете нажать в том "оригинальном" ответе